# Error with function `right` in select statement in hbm file

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, hibernate-mapping

i get an error with the following statement in a hibernate hbm file:

```
...
<subselect>
   <![CDATA[
      select t.colA, right(t.colB, 12) b
   ]]>
</subselect>
...
```

The error is `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "RIGHT": invalid Identifier`

Database: Oracle 11g
Hibernate: 3.5.6-Final

On the Java side i use Hibernate Criteria to retrieve the data from the database.
Without the `right` function it works without error.
The statement runs without error too directly executed with an sql client on the database.

Could the Criteria API causes the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle doesn't seem to support `RIGHT` function. You can try using `SUBSTR` function instead, something like:

```
select t.colA, substr(t.colB,-12) b
```

References:

[Oracle String Functions on oradev](http://www.oradev.com/oracle_string_functions.jsp)

[Oracle String Functions on techonthenet](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/)

[Oracle/PLSQL String Functions](http://psoug.org/reference/string_func.html)

[Oracle right function](http://oracle101.blogspot.com/2008/11/oracle-right-function.html)

Comment: My initial aim was to prepend a number with zeros up to 12 digits.
I've solved it with `select t.colA, lpad(t.colB,12, '0') b`
Thanks to Melih!

Answer (score 1):

the difference between substr(name,-3) vs substr(name,length(name)-3,3) vs substr(name,-3,3)

```
SUBSTR(Var, StartPos, Length)
```

**For example:**

```
SUBSTR("HELLO", LENGTH("HELLO") - 3) -> "ELLO"
SUBSTR("HELLO", LENGTH("HELLO") - 3, 3) -> "ELL"
SUBSTR("HELLO", -3) -> "LLO"
```

Don't use LENGTH(Name) - 3, because it is last 4 characters. Use -3 instead.